# Is there a way to hide certain part of a web page based on a custom guard with Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, web, authorization, laravel-blade

I know you can restrict controller function access with

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

But that controls the access for the whole webpage or blade file.

I want to show parts of a website only to some users based on a custom guard, like for admins. I know you could use `@auth` or `@guest` for normal authorization, but is there a way to do the same thing for a new guard?

(Sorry if dumb question)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use just simple control structures inside blade 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#control-structures

These could check anything, including guards.

Auth guards can be added with the included blade directives as you suggested yourself like:

```php
@auth('admin')
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest('admin')
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Or if you want something else, you could extend blade, and define an own directive
like @isSuperAdmin or whatever

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade

Answer (score 0):

try this..

@if(auth()->guard('guard_name')->check())
   .......
@endif

this way you can show a certain part to a specific user.